# extract word between 2nd underscore and 3rd underscore or space

Tags: regex

i want to extract the word after the 2nd & 3rd underscore (`_`) or the word between the 2nd underscore & space.

my sample data would be:

```
COL_POS_CJMA_CA_03.09.17
COL_DPU_CJER_CK_03.08.17
COL_POS_CJNE CA_03.09.2017
COL_DPU_CJEK CK_03.08.2017
```

my results should be:

```
CJMA
CJER
CJNE
CJEK
```

I already have this `_[^_]*_([^_]*)_`
And I could extract the 1st two results. 
If any one could help me extract the 3rd & 4th results

A regex that says between the 3rd underscore or a space

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could go for

```
^(?:[^_]+_){2}([^_ ]+)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/XF06yH/1/).

---

Broken down, this says:

```
^         # beginning of string
(?:       # non-capturing group
    [^_]+ # not _, at least once
    _     # _
){2}      # repeat the group twice
([^_ ]+)  # capture characters not _ or spaces to group 1
```

... or, split by `_` and analyze the result as an array, ie `result[2]`.

Comment: i need to extract the dates in each data.

Comment: @Amethyst please delete your comments that say "thanks" or do not pertain to this answer.  Please read SO's rules and guidelines so you know how to behave at SO.