# Extract value between second and third underscore in R

Tags: r

I have a data below in the dataframe column-

```
X_ABC_123_DF</n>
A_NJU_678_PP</n>
J_HH_99_LL</n>
II_00_777_PPP</n>
```

I want to extract the value between second and third underscore for each row in the dataframe, which i am planning to create a new column and store those values.. I found one way on SO mentioned below, but they haven't mentioned how to write this in R. I am not sure how to write its regex function.

```
^(?:[^_]+_){2}([^_ ]+)<br>
```

[extract word between 2nd underscore and 3rd underscore or space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42853709/extract-word-between-2nd-underscore-and-3rd-underscore-or-space)

Comment: Seems silly to use regex for such a simple operation. Just split on the underscore and pick the second value. In Python and Ruby: `"X_ABC_123_DF".split("_")[1]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A few solutions:

```
df$values = sapply(strsplit(df$V1, "_"), function(x) x[3])

df$values = gsub("(.*_){2}(\\d+)_.+", "\\2", df$V1)

library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
  mutate(values = str_extract(V1, "\\d+(?=_[a-zA-Z]+.+$)"))
```

**Result:**

```
                 V1 values
1  X_ABC_123_DF</n>    123
2  A_NJU_678_PP</n>    678
3    J_HH_99_LL</n>     99
4 II_00_777_PPP</n>    777
```

**Data:**

```
df = read.table(text = "X_ABC_123_DF</n>
                A_NJU_678_PP</n>
                J_HH_99_LL</n>
                II_00_777_PPP</n>", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Will this code automatically extract N number of data rows? , and the output, can this be stored in a column format next to the original data column thatw e used to extract?

Comment: @Joe You certainly can! All three solutions are vectorized, meaning it works no matter the number of rows. Also note that for the first two, I didn't use `mutate` to keep it `Base R` only. See my updates.

Comment: That worked like a charm. I initially thought, sine there were multiple columns, it will remove them and just have values column.. But it retained all of them and added the values column in the end which is great

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Assume the input is a data frame `df` with a single column `V1`.  Read it in using `read.table` with `sep="_"` and then pick out the third column.  No packages or regular expressions are used.  If `df$V1` is already character (as opposed to factor) then the `as.character` could be omitted.

```
read.table(text = as.character(df$V1), sep = "_")$V3
## [1] 123 678  99 777
```

**2)** If the third column is the only one that contains digits (which is the case for the sample data in the question) then it would be sufficient to replace each non-digit with the empty string:

```
as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", df$V1))
## [1] 123 678  99 777
```