# Extract characters between first and third period

Tags: r, regex

Basically what the title says, I have a vector of character strings and for each element I want to extract everything between the first and third period. E.g.

```
s <- c("random.0.0.word.1.0", "different.0.02.words.15.6", "different.0.1.words.4.2")
```

The result should be:

```
"0.0" "0.02" "0.1"
```

I have tried adapting code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42853709/extract-word-between-2nd-underscore-and-3rd-underscore-or-space) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46591633/extract-value-between-second-and-third-underscore-in-r) but failed. Any advice much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can capture as a group by matching characters not a `.` (`[^.]+`) from the start (`^`) of the string, followed by a dot (`\\.`) and then capture all the characters between the first and the third dot, in the replacement use the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group (`(...)`)

```
sub("^[^.]+\\.([^.]+\\.[^.]+)\\..*", "\\1", s)
#[1] "0.0"  "0.02" "0.1"
```

---

Or it can be also done with `substr` after getting the position of the dots

```
lst1 <- gregexpr('.', s, fixed = TRUE)
substring(s, sapply(lst1, `[`, 1) + 1, sapply(lst1, `[`, 3) - 1)
#[1] "0.0"  "0.02" "0.1"
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to do this, without using any fancy regex features, is just to split on `.` and then grab the bits we need:

```
library(stringr)
library(purrr)

str_split(s, "\\.") %>% 
  map_chr(~ paste0(.[2:3], collapse = "."))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `sub` to capture as little as possible between 1st and 3rd period.

```
sub(".*?\\.(.*?\\..*?)\\..*", "\\1", s)
#[1] "0.0"  "0.02" "0.1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way with *unglue*, which some might find less intimidating :

```r
library(unglue)
s <- c("random.0.0.word.1.0", "different.0.02.words.15.6", "different.0.1.words.4.2")
unglue_vec(s, "{=[^.]+}.{x}.{=[^.]+}.{=[^.]+}.{=[^.]+}")
#> [1] "0.0"  "0.02" "0.1"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

The subpatterns `[^.]+` are sequences of "non dots", not named (nothing on the lhs of `=`) because we don't want to extract them.