# Split and substring a list of strings

Tags: r, regex, string

I have a list of strings with different substrings divided by '_' character, I would like to get an specific substring from this list to form a new list:

This list of strings looks like:

```
lista <- c('ORD_EVI_19870401_MAXI_002','CAB_EVI_19850301_MAXI_003','CAB_EVI_19850401_MAXI_001','PIC_EVI_19920301_MAXI_001','PIC_EVI_19920401_MAXI_003')
```

I know this works:

```
lista <-  substr(lista, 9,12)
```

With the output i'm looking for:

```
[1] "1987" "1985" "1985" "1992" "1992"
```

But sometimes the length of each string is different and it doesn't work.

How could I combine `strsplit` and `substr` functions to get the first four characters of the third substring in each element of the list?

Comment: Please try and avoid naming your objects with predefined functions. `list` is a function in base R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way could be:

```
substr(sapply(strsplit(list, "_", fixed = TRUE), "[", 3), 1, 4)

[1] "1987" "1985" "1985" "1992" "1992"
```

Or with `tstrsplit()` from `data.table`:

```
sapply(tstrsplit(list, "_", fixed = TRUE, keep = 3), substr, 1, 4)
```

Just a small comparison of approaches:

```
library(microbenchmark)

lst <- rep(list, 100000)

microbenchmark(
 tmfmnk_strsplit = substr(sapply(strsplit(lst, "_", fixed = TRUE), "[", 3), 1, 4),
 tmfmnk_tstrsplit = sapply(tstrsplit(lst, "_", fixed = TRUE, keep = 3), substr, 1, 4),
 Ronak_Shah_strsplit = sapply(strsplit(lst, "_"), function(x) substr(x[3], 1, 4)),
 Ronak_Shah_sub = sub("^(?:[^_]+_){2}(.{4}).*", "\\1", lst),
 Sotos_stringr_word = substr(stringr::word(lst, 3, 3, sep = '_'), 1, 4),
 Sotos_gsub = substr(gsub("\\D+", "", lst), 1, 4),
 patL_1 = str_sub(str_split(lst, pattern = "_", simplify = TRUE)[,3], start = 1, end = 4),
 patL_2 = str_split(lst, pattern = "_", simplify = TRUE)[,3] %>% str_sub(start = 1, end = 4), 
 times = 5
)

Unit: milliseconds
                expr       min        lq      mean    median         uq        max neval
     tmfmnk_strsplit  600.8501  615.2786  688.7693  618.1062   631.8959   977.7155     5
    tmfmnk_tstrsplit  383.7881  392.2930  596.2255  428.4289   445.8589  1330.7584     5
 Ronak_Shah_strsplit 4372.1978 4436.3701 4650.4455 4551.9226  4652.0911  5239.6461     5
      Ronak_Shah_sub  737.3849  756.7462  773.2315  759.4766   777.2293   835.3204     5
  Sotos_stringr_word 8298.2679 8459.3475 9452.5748 9954.5619 10255.8447 10294.8522     5
          Sotos_gsub 1299.2949 1323.2183 1479.6777 1386.1354  1446.8309  1942.9089     5
              patL_1  730.1206  731.3955  842.6071  813.4897   841.1782  1096.8517     5
              patL_2  635.8529  656.1035  818.8592  669.6658   713.0357  1419.6380     5
```

Answer (score 2):

Another idea is to use `gsub`, i.e.

```
substr(gsub('\\D+', '', list), 1, 4)
#[1] "1987" "1985" "1985" "1992" "1992"
```

Also `stringr` package and the (always fun) function `word`, i.e.

```
substr(stringr::word(list, 3, 3, sep = '_'), 1, 4)
#[1] "1987" "1985" "1985" "1992" "1992"
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach with `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)

str_sub(str_split(list, pattern = "_", simplify = TRUE)[,3],
        start = 1,
        end = 4)

#[1] "1987" "1985" "1985" "1992" "1992"
```

or the same but piping the code:

```
str_split(list, pattern = "_", simplify = TRUE)[,3] %>% 
  str_sub(start = 1,
        end = 4) 
#[1] "1987" "1985" "1985" "1992" "1992"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can split the string on `"_"`, and extract the first 4 characters of the 3rd part.

```
sapply(strsplit(lista, "_"), function(x) substr(x[3], 1, 4))
#[1] "1987" "1985" "1985" "1992" "1992"
```

Or a complete regex solution taking some help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42853770/3962914)

```
sub("^(?:[^_]+_){2}(.{4}).*", "\\1", lista)
#[1] "1987" "1985" "1985" "1992" "1992"
```

This extracts first 4 characters after 2nd underscore.